# Is my question (incorrectly) banned due to fighting with spam?

Tags: support, spam, spam-detection

It seems so, because I can not see my less-than-hour question in the "newest" tab. At this moment (i.e. the moment of writing **this** question) "newest" top questions are asked 8,9,...  hours ago.

I do not post link to my hidden question because I fear to be marked as spammer for this. Here is part of the link: questions/147243/edge-and-edges-tags-are-not-synonyms-but-probably-should

Comment: Should be good now; Deltik's answer has the details.

Answer (score 3):

You are *not* banned.  Instead, you were caught up in a bad time for Stack Exchange.

The cause of the problems is the recent server migrations.  As far as I can see, all Stack Exchange sites are affected except for Stack Overflow, which was the first to come back to life.

Stack Overflow Meta was taken down to read-only mode momentarily, but when it resumed operations, like the other sites, it still did not show new activity.

**The only thing we can do is wait it out.**

Until then, there is an ugly workaround to check out the latest questions:

1. Select the question ID of the most recent question.  Example: [meta.superuser.com/questions/**5573**](https://meta.superuser.com/q/5573/83694)
2. Increment that number until you reach a newer question.  **5574** and **5575** lead to an answer because IDs are assigned sequentially not only to questions, but **5576** is the next-newest question, which doesn't show up yet on the front page.

I found this question by incrementing the numbers.

<sup><sub>This answer was brought to you [from Super User land](https://meta.superuser.com/q/5576/83694).</sub></sup>

---

**UPDATE 03:19 AM UTC:** Stack Exchange is quickly coming back to life now!  It shouldn't be long until everything returns to normal.